# How to change the timestamp format shown when undo/redo in vim?

Tags: vim

When undo/redo in vim, the status shows like:

`1 change; before #33  12:03:05`

The time format is `HH:MM:SS`; but referring to [this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html#undo-tree), seems there are four possible formats:

- N seconds ago
- HH:MM:SS             (hour, minute, seconds)
- MM/DD HH:MM:SS       (idem, with month and day)
- YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS  (idem, with year)

Can I change this timestamp format shown? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [not likely](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/undo.c#L3098-L3121).

You can probably use some plugin ([Gundo](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Gundo) or [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) to name just two) to get desired output.